# Making a game trainer in C++?

Tags: c++, memory, pointers

Ok so i've messed with games before, but now i would like to make a trainer only problem is that there memory adresses changes every time i play it on a different computer or restart the game. Now i need to find a pointer but have no idea how.

So how do i find the pointer to the adress for ammo for any weapon with a memory scanner like CheatEngine 5.4?

Answer (score 4):

- step 1. search through memory for the value you are looking to change, and store all match locations
- step 2. do something in the game to change the value to a new value
- step 3. check all of the match locations, one of them should have the new value in it.
- step 4. write whatever you want into that location.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**: Search the value you want to change with cheat engine.

**Step 2**: If you have found the right address do right click on it and make a pointer scan for this address. Now you should get many base-addresses with some offsets.

**Step 3**: Close your game and repeat Step 1. Now copy the new address and click on rescan pointerscan (in the window that opened from step 2).Paste the new address in the rescan address field and rescan. Then you should only get the right base-addresses + offsets.

**Step 4**: To always find the right address do readprocessmemory(baseaddress+offset)

Comment: its better to copy **value** again for re-scanning memory because value is easy to find in memory.

Answer (score 0):

http://forum.cheatengine.org/viewtopic.php?t=26540 i found this on the cheat engine webpage they have a section dedicated to pointer it could prob help.